# Hbase MapReduce: how to use custom class as value for the mapper and/or reducer?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I am trying to familiarize myself with Hadoop/Hbase MapReduce jobs to be able to properly write them. Right now I have an Hbase instance with a table called dns with some DNS records. I tried to make a simple unique domains counter that outputs a file and it worked. Right now, I only use `IntWritable` or `Text` and I was wondering if it's possible to use custom objects for my Mapper/Reducer. I tried to do it myself, but I'm getting

```
Error: java.io.IOException: Initialization of all the collectors failed. Error in last collector was :null
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.createSortingCollector(MapTask.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.access$100(MapTask.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.<init>(MapTask.java:698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:770)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1869)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.init(MapTask.java:1011)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.createSortingCollector(MapTask.java:402)
    ... 9 more
```

Since I'm new to this, I don't actually know what to do. I'm guessing I have to implement one or more interfaces or to extend an abstract class, but I can't find [here](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html) or on the internet a proper example.

I tried to make a simple domains counter from my dns table, but using a class as a wrapper over an integer (for didactic purposes only). My **Map class** looks like this:

```
public class Map extends TableMapper<Text, MapperOutputValue> {
    private static byte[] columnName = "fqdn".getBytes();
    private static byte[] columnFamily = "d".getBytes();

    public void map(ImmutableBytesWritable row, Result value, Context context)
            throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        String fqdn = new String(value.getValue(columnFamily, columnName));
        Text key = new Text();
        key.set(fqdn);
        context.write(key, new MapperOutputValue(1));

    }
}
```

**The Reducer**:

```
public class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, MapperOutputValue, Text, IntWritable> {
    @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<MapperOutputValue> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        int i = 0;
        for (MapperOutputValue val : values) {
            i += val.getCount();
        }

        context.write(key, new IntWritable(i));
    }
}
```

And a part of my **Driver/Main** function:

```
 TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(
                "dns",
                scan,
                Map.class,
                Text.class,
                MapperOutputValue.class,
                job);

/* Set output parameters */
job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
```

As I said, **MapperOutputValue** is just a simple class that contains a private Integer, a constructor with a parameter, a getter and a setter. I also tried adding a `toString` method but it still doesn't work.

So my question is: what's the best way to use custom classes as an output of the mapper/input for the reducer? Also, let's say I want to use a class with multiple fields as an final output of the reducer. What should this class implement/extends? Is it a good idea or I should stick to using "primitives" as IntWritable or Text?

Thank!

Comment: Does `MapperOutputValue` implement `Writable`? http://bigdatums.net/2016/06/05/how-to-create-a-custom-writable-for-hadoop/. If you're not so familiar with MapReduce it could be worth breaking this down into an easier problem where you read DNS records from an HDFS file, and then add the HBase connectivity once that works.

Comment: @BenWatson after I posted this I implemented the `WritableComparable` interface and I was able to make it work, but only with integers. I don't know what methods are the best to work with Strings. Anyway, thanks for the article

Comment: @BenWatson you can answer with the example from that article (or another one, how you wish), I'll accept it. I made it work the way I want, the article was very useful. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MapOutputValue` should implement `Writable`, so that it can be serialised between tasks in the MapReduce job. Replacing `MapOutputJob` with the below should work:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable;

import java.io.DataInput;
import java.io.DataOutput;
import java.io.IOException;

public class DomainCountWritable implements Writable {
    private Text domain;
    private IntWritable count;

    public DomainCountWritable() {
        this.domain = new Text();
        this.count = new IntWritable(0);
    }

    public DomainCountWritable(Text domain, IntWritable count) {
        this.domain = domain;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public Text getDomain() {
        return this.domain;
    }

    public IntWritable getCount() {
        return this.count;
    }

    public void setDomain(Text domain) {
        this.domain = domain;
    }

    public void setCount(IntWritable count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
        this.domain.readFields(in);
        this.count.readFields(in);
    }

    public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
        this.domain.write(out);
        this.count.write(out);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.domain.toString() + "\t" + this.count.toString();
    }
}
```